# How to do access management with this architecture?

Tags: oauth-2.0, api-design

I am working on a system with the following architecture structure (relevant to the question):

- Frontend server (static assets + proxy API calls + sessions management)
- API server + domain specific database
- Frontend and API are deployed in the same private network
- API server blocks public access
- Frontend server allows public access with IP whitelisting, API gateway in front of the frontend.

Authentication is done against an external Identity Provider following standard authorization code flow with the frontend acting as private client.

For legacy reasons, access management is not centralized in the Identity Provider.
Instead I am being asked to build and maintain user and access management capabilities within the system.

Essentially the access token returned by the Identity Provider only returns a generic claim which I can use to establish if the identity can use the system or not. In order to establish if the identity can execute an operation against the API I need to build a custom policy enforcement point.
It is worth noting the only possible audience for the access token is the public domain of the system.

I am planning to create a separate database specific to user access, to avoid decoupling with the domain specific database and enable easy migration to centralized access management in the future.
The database would link the identity returned by the Identity Provider to the access rights of a user. Both pieces of information would be submitted by an admin when registering the user.

My question is twofold:

1. Which component is the resource server ? Can the API be the resource server when it is not publicly available ?
2. If the API is the resource server, which component should be responsible to access the users database to check access rights and why ?
   If such component is the frontend would you recommend to use the same cache for sessions and user access information ?